# AS3 - Error #1056: Cannot create property 0 on Boolean

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, boolean

I'm in need of creating multiple dynamic arrays and seem to have found exactly what I need at https://jadendreamer.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/flash-as3-tutorial-how-to-create-2d-or-3d-dynamic-multi-dimensional-arrays/

Example 1:

```
var multiDimensionalArray:Array = new Array();
var boolArray:Array;
var MAX_ROWS = 5;
var MAX_COLS = 5;

//initalize the arrays
for (var row = 0; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
{
    boolArray = new Array();    
    for (var col = 0; col <= MAX_COLS; col++){
        boolArray.push(false);
    }    
    multiDimensionalArray.push(boolArray);
}

//now we can set the values of the array as usual
for (var row = 0; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
{
    for (var col = 0; col <= MAX_COLS; col++){
        boolArray[row][col] = true;
        trace('boolArray ' + row + ',' + col + ' = ' + boolArray[row][col]);
    }
}
```

However, when testing either of the snippets provided at the site I end up with error `"#1056: Cannot create property 0 on Boolean."`

"`Automatically declare stage instances`" is checked.

I've spent hours on this and I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't quite get it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `boolArray`from the top, currently you're always adding the same Array to your 2D-Array, I doubt this is intentional.

```
var multiDimensionalArray:Array = new Array();
//var boolArray:Array; //remove this line
var MAX_ROWS = 5;
var MAX_COLS = 5;

//initalize the arrays
for (var row = 0; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
{
    var boolArray:Array = new Array(); //create a new Array here

    for (var col = 0; col <= MAX_COLS; col++)
        boolArray.push(false);
    }

    multiDimensionalArray.push(boolArray);
}
```

This won't solve your problem though, but it will prevent further problems.

To solve your problem you need to look at your second for loop structure, at the bottom of the snippet.

Currently, you're trying to access `boolArray[row][col]`. But this Object is not a 2D Array, it's a 1D Array. So you take the object at the index `row`, then try to change the value of the variable that has the name of the value of `col`, i.e. 0. As you are aware, Boolean doesn't have a variable called 0.

To put it simply, what you're doing here:

`boolArray[row][col] = true`

is actually

`boolArray[row].0 = true`

or

`boolArray[row]["0"] = true`

To solve this, you should refer to your actual 2D Array.

```
for (var row = 0; row <= MAX_ROWS; row++)
{
    for (var col = 0; col <= MAX_COLS; col++)
        multiDimensionalArray[row][col] = true;
        trace('multiDimensionalArray' + row + ',' + col + ' = ' + multiDimensionalArray[row][col]);
    }
}
```

To sum it all up in one sentence: You used the wrong Array Object.

Comment: Thank you!  I obviously have a lot to learn about arrays - I appreciate the step by step explanation.

Comment: No problem. Learning something is always good. And it's the tutorials "fault" really, for not giving a good explanation and containing errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to register the row array.

```
boolArray[row] = new Array();
```

For example, If you want to create an 1*3 array
code the below.

```
var a:Array = new Array();
a[0] = new Array();
a[0][0] = '1';
a[0][1] = '2';
a[0][2] = '3';
```

To know the Basics of Multi dimensional array click [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee9.html)

Comment: That is not the problem though, the error message specifically is about creating a property on a Boolean object. Even if he doesn't redefine the boolArray variable for each row, it should still "work", just that all the rows are the same.

Comment: Thank you for the link - I've been working on learning to properly use arrays for a couple of days now and figuring out how to create multi dimensional dynamic arrays is proving to be trickier than expected.